# Ajax Not passing post data to php script

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I'm very very stuck, Currently trying to send data from an ajax function, to a php script on an external url. But no post data is being passed to the other URL?

**HTML**

```
<form action="" id="actionForm" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<figure class="info-wrap">
                    <i class="fa-thin fa-cloud-arrow-up"></i>
                    <label for="logo-upload">Drag & Drop files or <span>Browse</span></label>
                    <p>Supported formats: PNG, JPG, PDF, WORD & ZIP</p>
                    <input type="file" id="myfile" name="myfile">
                </figure>
                <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Upload" id="upload_Logo_file">
    </form>
```

**Jquery**

```
var client = $('input[name=clientID]').val();
    $("#upload_Logo_file").on("click", function() {
        $('#actionForm').attr({'data-target': "uploadajax" });
    });
$('#actionForm').submit(function(e) {
    var attr = $(this).attr("data-target");
    if (attr == "uploadajax") {
        var imageData = { 
            myfile: $('#myfile').prop("files")[0],
            name: "john",
        };
        $.ajax({
            url: "External URL" + client,
            type: "POST",
            data: imageData,
            dataType: "json",
            encode: true,
            processData: false,
            contentType: 'application/json', 
        }).done(function(data) {
            if (!data.success) {
                if (data.errors.myfile) {
                    $('#actionForm').append('<div class="help-block">' + data.errors.myfile + "</div>");
                }
              } else {
                $("form").html(
                  '<div class="alert alert-success">' + data.message + "</div>"
                );
              }
        
        });

        event.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

**PHP**

```
<?php
/**
 * Send as JSON
 */
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type");

$file = $_POST['name'];

$clientId = ($_GET['client']);

$errors = [];
$data = [];

//create directory based on client ID paramter passed
if (!file_exists(__DIR__ . "/$clientId")) {
    mkdir(__DIR__ . "/$clientId", 0777, true);
}

$target_dir = __DIR__ . "/$clientId/";
$target_file = $target_dir . $_FILES["myfile"]["name"];
$uploadOk = 1;
$imageFileType = $_FILES["myfile"]["type"];

$allowedTypes = [
    'image/png' => 'png',
    'image/jpeg' => 'jpg',
    'application/pdf' => 'pdf',
    'application/msword' => 'doc',
    'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document' => 'docx',
    'application/zip' => 'zip',
];

echo $_FILES["myfile"]["name"];

if (!file_exists($target_file)) {// Check if file already exists
    if ($_FILES["myfile"]["size"] < 3145728) {// Check filesize
        if(in_array($imageFileType, array_keys($allowedTypes))) { //check filetypes
            if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["myfile"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
                echo "The file ". htmlspecialchars( basename( $_FILES["myfile"]["name"])). " has been uploaded.";
            } else {
                $errors['myfile'] = 'There was a problem Uploading Your File';
            }
        } else {
            $errors['myfile'] = 'Sorry, only JPG, JPEG, PNG & GIF files are allowed.';
        }
    } else {
        $errors['myfile'] = 'File to large, Must be 3 MB or less.';
    }
} else {
    $errors['myfile'] = "$target_file File already Exists +  $file";
}

if (!empty($errors)) {
    $data['success'] = false;
    $data['errors'] = $errors;
} else {
    $data['success'] = true;
    $data['message'] = 'Success!';
}

echo json_encode($data);

?>
```

If I remove

```
        processData: false,
        contentType: 'application/json',
```

From the ajax script, It posts John to the script, But wont pass the file prop. Obviously I dont need the name john I just need the file prop. No matter what I do it doesn't seem to be working.

It just wont pass the data to the external url. I know the php form works if I just action it without ajax. But with ajax it just wont post the file information.

Any help would be appreciated :)

Comment: I'm pretty sure that for some reason you'll never be able to get `POST` data from AJAX in the `$_POST` variable. Try `$file = file_get_contents("php://input",true)` instead.

Comment: `var attr = $(this).attr("data-target");` Where is `data-target` set? Did you use your browser's DevTools/Network tab to see what gets sent/received?

Comment: @outlaw That returned [object Object] so thats a good start at least. at least i know its passing data now

Comment: @brombeer Sorry i omitted that as its just an irrelevant bit of code its but ill add it to question

Comment: @outlaw that just isn't true. There are lots of examples online